# I want to make a asp.net website in blogger..is it possible.what are the alternate ways?

Tags: asp.net, blogger

I have been thinking of creating a website with asp.net.

Is it possible to develop asp.net sites in blogger? Wat i have seen is write something in plaintext or html and it wil be posted...but i want to write asp.net code using sql server in bloggger.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of blog engines for asp.net.  http://www.dotnetblogengine.net/ is one that I've heard is easy to use.

You can't write an asp.net application *in blogger* because blogger is a free service offered by Google, hosted on their own servers.

I'd assume you're referring to the way of inputting text.  If that's the case, check out [Textile.NET](http://textilenet.codeplex.com/).  This will simplify textual input and allow you to store values in the database which don't include any html.